# SVN restricting branch deletion

Tags: svn

I am new to svn. In my project some one was deleting the branches from svn. How to restrict the users for deleting the branches.
Our svn server is in linux and developers are working on windows environment using TSVN.
Can any one  help me restrict

Comment: Related: [SVN - how to restrict user access to certain folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6091743)

Comment: Googling `SVN restricting branch deletion` shows some promising hits.

Answer (score 1):

1. [svnperms.py](http://prabhugs.wordpress.com/tag/svnperms-py/) in pre-commit hook
2. Don't worry snd do nothing - physically deleted branch still stored in history and can be checkouted later, using corresponding URL with PEG-revision

   `svn ls http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/`
   `Leichtbau-Deutsch/`
   `branche-francaise/`
   `i18n/`

But in graph Greetings branch is discoverable and can be checkouted

[image: Revision graph]

```
>svn co http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/Greetings@16
A    Greetings\Hello.txt
 U   Greetings
Checked out revision 16.
```