# SVN prohibit further commits to a library

Tags: svn

Is there a way where I can prohibit myself and other users from commiting further changes to a folder in our SVN without having server side access?

I would like to see a message like:

"You're not allowed to check in any further updates to this project. You can only add new files"
Whenever someone is doing: svn ci PATH...

How would I do this? and how would we control what parts of the repo is locked and not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVN - how to restrict user access to certain folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091743/svn-how-to-restrict-user-access-to-certain-folders)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new to SVN. I think this is a server side configuration. I have not seen the authz anywhere in my setup.
I only have user access

Comment: If you want to ensure that nobody can write to a specific folder, there's no other option than setting this on the server

Comment: Okay. That is bad news.